# Predicting with Nan in input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I trained a (0,1) model with tensorflow but without Nans in it. Is there any way to predict some values with Nan in it. I use 'adam' as optimizer.

> Making model:

```
input_size = 16
output_size = 2
hidden_layer_size = 50

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_layer_size, activation='relu'), # 1st hidden layer
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_layer_size, activation='relu'), # 2nd hidden layer
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(output_size, activation='softmax') # output layer
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

batch_size = 100

max_epochs = 20

early_stopping=tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping()

model.fit(train_inputs, # train inputs
          train_targets, # train targets
          batch_size=batch_size, # batch size
          epochs=max_epochs, # epochs that we will train for (assuming early stopping doesn't kick in)
          callbacks=[early_stopping],
          validation_data=(validation_inputs, validation_targets), # validation data
          verbose = 1 # making sure we get enough information about the training process
          )
```

> Potential input I'd like to add:

```
x=np.array([[ 0.8048038 ,  2.22810658,  0.7184345 , -0.59266753,  1.73062328,
         0.69392477, -1.35764524, -0.55833263,  0.10620523,  1.31206921,
        -1.07966389,  1.04462389, -0.99787875,  0.797905  , -0.35954954,
          np.NaN]])
```

> The return I get:

```
array([[nan, nan]], dtype=float32)
```

So is there any way to achive it?

Comment: It makes sense to remove nan/inf from the data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optimizer needs to be able to do computations with the input. This means NaN is not a valid input for that, as there really is no good way to do anything with it in this case. You therefore have to either replace these NaNs with meaningful numbers, or you will be unable to use this data point and you will have to drop it like so:

```
x = x[np.isfinite(x)]
```